# How to display categories in a selectbox with search button for search product category wise on custom CMS page?

Tags: php, ajax, search, magento-1.9, categories

I am using magento 1.9.2 and i want to display categories in a select-box and sub-categories in an other select-box and search product with respective catgories.

I want to have two drop-down the first are for the categories and the second for the subcategories and When i select the categories in the first drop-down the second drop-down must changed and display the subcategories of the category selected in the first drop-down.

Means i want first dropdown to display top categories and once something is selected there the 2nd dropdown is automatically populated with subcategories of the category selected in 1st dropdown?

This all on any custom CMS page.

Answer (score 0):

You basically got to have the data for both of them, the sub categories should be prepared to be easy to access after selecting the main category and therefore, a map would be a perfect solution for the sub-categories data type.
so what you could do is hold the categories in the following way:

```
[{"name": "category 1", "id": 1}, {"name": "category 2", "id": 2}, {"name": "category 3", "id": 3}]
```

and the sub-categories in the following way so it can be easily accessed with his key and the main-categories id:

```
{'category_1' : [{},{},{}],'category_2' : [{},{},{}],'category_3' : [{},{},{}]
```

this approach will gain you the best performance. however, in case you got a lot of data that can't be loaded to the client all together, you'll need to create another ajax query to load the sub-categories on-change of the main-category.

i hope this makes sense to you..

Comment: this is JSON format for categories. Can you help me with code. I am trying to do customize form.mini.phtml file but not getting correct accurate result.  http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2011/11/search-by-category-in-magento.html i have used this solution, category displayed but search not working on selection on categroy

Comment: i'm not familiar with that specific code. if you'll follow the guidelines i described you should do it without too much hassle.. on-load, create a javascript object that will hold a tree of your categories and subcategories and display that accordingly